# Dart: Failed to load "test/xxx_test.dart": Instance of 'OutsideTestException'

Tags: dart, testing

When I try to run the following test:

```dart
import 'package:my_project/my_file.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  group('int extensions:', () {
    expect(1.digits(), 1);
    expect(10.digits(), 2);
    expect(100.digits(), 3);
  });
}
```

I get the following error message:

> Failed to load "test/my_file_test.dart": Instance of 'OutsideTestException'

The answer is probably obvious most people coming here now, but it took me a while to realize what was wrong. I'm adding my answer below for other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to call `test` and not just `group`:

```dart
void main() {
  group('int extensions:', () {
    test('digits', () {
      expect(1.digits(), 1);
      expect(10.digits(), 2);
      expect(100.digits(), 3);
    });
  });
}
```